# Can I use Bash autocompletions for kubectl in fish?

Tags: kubectl, fish

Does anybody use fish shell with Kubectl commands? This Bash completion
`source <(kubectl completion bash | sed 's/kubectl/k/g')`
works like dizzying charm for Bash. But how to do that same thing in fish shell?

Answer (score 2):

Fish is not generally compatible with bash, and bash's completion system is quite different from fish's. It's possible to jerry-rig *some* of it (if a tool takes $COMP_CWORD and such), but the real solution is to use a completion script written for fish, like https://github.com/evanlucas/fish-kubectl-completions.

There was also some work to integrate fish completions [upstream](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/pull/754), but that has seemingly stalled.

Comment: Thanks so much @faho. I appreciate the command and responds. You are right fish != bash and fish is not compatible. In Fish shell, all I want to instead of using kubectl, i just need to use "k" as alias but kubectl completion should also work with "k" alias too.

Answer (score 1):

In Fish this would easiest be solved with an abbreviation. Running `abbr --add --global k kubectl` will permanently add an abbreviation `k` that gets replaced with `kubectl` when you press space/enter. After the auto-replacement, any existing autocompletions you already have installed for `kubectl` will work as normal. (See the [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/included/optional-kubectl-configs-fish/) for installing kubectl autocompletions if you don't have them already.)

Abbrevations in fish can replace use-cases that many other shells use aliases for, but still allow editing the command line in case you want to tweak something manually. For example, I have a [fish port](https://github.com/DrPhil/kubectl-fish-abbr) of the common [kubectl-aliases](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectl-aliases) that adds the shortcuts as abbreviations.